# What are the alternatives to ORM?

Tags: php, orm, frameworks

I am creating a php mvc framework for learning purposes.
 I have a really simple PDO wrapper but I feel it is still too much trouble for the user to write all the sql queries themselves. So I want to implement something like ORM like almost all php frameworks have. However, I am not a big fan of ORM and was wondering if there were any (good) alternatives to ORM. If not, then can someone provide me with a simple good ORM example?

Comment: never hear of the words `simple`, `good` and `ORM` in the same phrase.

Comment: So do you mean that ORM is never simple AND good or do you mean that ORM is never simple OR good?

Comment: Doctrine is good and simple enough to use. Follow the Getting Started with Doctrine tutorial: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Ted Neward provides a detailed accounting of the problem with ORMs: http://blogs.tedneward.com/post/the-vietnam-of-computer-science/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative can be the one described by Tony Marston on *Using PHP Objects to access your Database Tables* ([Part 1](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/databaseobjects.html)) ([Part 2](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/databaseobjects2.html)). With that he construct a [DML Class](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/infrastructure.html#dml.class) and finally a [Data Dictionary](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/data-dictionary.html).